# F#: Why does this code throws a System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, ...'

Tags: f#, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.7.2

I created a F# Library (.NET Standard 2.0) and a WPF App (.NET Framework 4.7.2)

On the F# library, I have a file that I defined as a Resource:
[image: File]
[image: File Properties]

This is using this code of the library:

```
let LeResourceFile(resourceName) = 
    let assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    //var resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt";

    use stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)
    use reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)

    let result = reader.ReadToEnd();

    result

let LogoBanco (CodigoDoBanco:string) =
    match CodigoDoBanco with
    | "001" -> LeResourceFile("BoletoBancarioFacil.templates.Logos.BB.png")
    | _ -> ""
```

When I try to access the library function (.NET Standard 2.0) from the C# (NET 4.7.2) then I get this Exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

**Why does this happens and how to fix it, to make it work?**

EDIT: I tried to find this System.Runtime on the NuGet on that F# library, but this specific version is not avaliable:
[image: NuGet F#]

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at BoletoBancarioFacil.HTML.LogoBanco(String CodigoDoBanco)
   at BoletoBancarioFacil.HTML.GeraBoletoHTML(Decimal amount, String LinhaDigitavel, String CodigoBarras) in C:\Users\tonyv\source\repos\siteApelosUrgentes\socio\cadastro\BoletoBancarioFacil\HTML.fs:line 49
   at cadastro.MainWindow.GeraHTMLboleto(Titulo titulo) in C:\Users\tonyv\source\repos\siteApelosUrgentes\socio\cadastro\cadastro\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 389
   at cadastro.MainWindow.ExibeBoleto(Titulo titulo, Boolean Imprime) in C:\Users\tonyv\source\repos\siteApelosUrgentes\socio\cadastro\cadastro\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 737
   at cadastro.MainWindow.ListBoxTitulos_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\tonyv\source\repos\siteApelosUrgentes\socio\cadastro\cadastro\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 987

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/tonyv/source/repos/siteApelosUrgentes/socio/cadastro/cadastro/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : BoletoBancarioFacil, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\tonyv\source\repos\siteApelosUrgentes\socio\cadastro\cadastro\bin\Debug\cadastro.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.1.2.0 redirected to 4.1.2.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/tonyv/source/repos/siteApelosUrgentes/socio/cadastro/cadastro/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/tonyv/source/repos/siteApelosUrgentes/socio/cadastro/cadastro/bin/Debug/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/tonyv/source/repos/siteApelosUrgentes/socio/cadastro/cadastro/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/tonyv/source/repos/siteApelosUrgentes/socio/cadastro/cadastro/bin/Debug/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: OK, I added the Stack Trace info.

Comment: On this case, when I downgrade the C# WPF App to .NET 4.7.0. and it works without that Exception. https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481#issuecomment-429653699

Comment: Have you tried copying the .dll to the same folder as the application?

Comment: No, I added the F# Project as a reference, using Visual Studio. So it Builds and automatically copies the files.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like one of your libraries isn't compatible with the dotnet runtime you are using.  You can usually fix this with binding redirects.  I would highly recommend using [paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) to manage your library dependencies.  I would also take a look at the [binding redirects feature](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/dependencies-file.html#Controlling-assembly-binding-redirects).  It can fix some of these version inconsistencies by creating runtime configs that remap the wrong versions at runtime onto the one you actually have.  You can create these `.config` files manually as well but it's a pain.  Here is an example redirect to keep all the dependent F# core versions mapped onto the one I actually have in a project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <Paket>True</Paket>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" 
    publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" 
    newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    </configuration>
```